# Not able to understand this C program

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to programming, not getting the code below. This program checks if a character `c` is in the string `s`.

```
int is_in(char *s, char c){
  while(*s){
    if(*s==c) return 1;
    else s++;
  return 0;
}
```

The main thing confusing me is, how the `while` loop will stop, as, I think `s++` will go through all over the memory, after the end of string also. Can anyone explain this please? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: While(*s) will save this loop in the end because strings end with null so it will terminate even if it does not find the target

Comment: Unless the string didn't have a null terminator....then you are screwed until it hits a random null byte

Comment: I'd say your code listing needs a closing brace somewhere, doesn't it?

Comment: @BaileyKocin If the string doesn't have a null terminator, it's not a string.

Comment: @glglgl Mind partially blown

Comment: Clean-up looks like this: https://godbolt.org/z/12t9bc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop stops when `*s` is 0, i.e. at the end of the NUL-terminated string.

The idiomatic way of modelling strings in C is to *terminate* them with 0. Note that if `s` is not formed in this way, then the behaviour of your function is *undefined*.

Personally I'd prefer the function to be `int is_in(const char *s, char c)` to signify to the caller that the function doesn't modify the string.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition that the pointer `s` will continue to loop indefinitely would be correct were it not for two things:

- C strings are terminated by a null-terminator (the character `'\0'`). This acts as a sentinel value for functions that process strings; this is necessary since when an array is passed to a function it decays to a pointer to its first element, losing length information.
- The loop condition `while(*s)` will be false when the null terminator is reached.

In fact, `while(*s) { loop-body; s++; }` is a well-known idiom in C for processing strings.

Comment: Thanks. But, I have another question, doesn't the `s++` increase the memory location by `1` unit of the type(here 1byte)? Then how it will read `\0` at a time? As `\ ` will take 1 byte and `0` will be in next byte.

Comment: @AshisGhosh Wrong, `'\0'` is an escape sequence for a character with the numeric value of zero, it is one byte

Answer (score 0):

The string `char *s` is supposed to end with terminating `NUL`. The value of `NUL` is zero. Zero is what `*s` is supposed to "expand" to eventually.